# .map function in react not display any data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have react code as following:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

interface AllEmployeeDataState {
    empList: EmployeeData[];
    loading: boolean;
}

export class AllEmployee extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, AllEmployeeDataState> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { empList: [], loading: true };

        fetch('api/Employee/Index')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ loading: false });
                this.state.empList.push(data);
                console.log(this.state.empList);
            });

        this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
    }

    public render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : this.renderEmployeeTable(this.state.empList);

        return <div>
            <h1>Employee Data</h1>
            <p>
                <Link to="/Employee/Detail">Create New</Link>
            </p>
            {contents}
        </div>;
    }

    private handleEdit(id: number) {
        this.props.history.push("/Employee/Detail/" + id);
    }

    private renderEmployeeTable(empList: EmployeeData[]) {
        return <table className='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>EmployeeId</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Designation</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {empList.map((emp, i) => (
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <td>{emp.FldId}</td>
                        <td>{emp.FldName}</td>
                        <td>{emp.FldGender}</td>
                        <td>{emp.FldDesignation}</td>
                        <td>{emp.FldCity}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>;
    }
}

export class EmployeeData {
    FldId: number = 0;
    FldName: string = "";
    FldFatherName: string = "";
    FldGender: number = 0;
    FldReligion: number = 0;
    FldCnic: string = "";
    FldDob: Date = new Date;
    FldCity: number = 0;
    FldPermanentAddress: string = "";
    FldContactNumber: string = "";
    FldNationality: number = 0;
    FldEmailId: string = "";
    FldStatus: boolean = false;
    FldDateOfJoining: Date = new Date;
    FldCreatedAt: Date = new Date;
    FldCreatedBy: number = 0;
    FldUpdatedAt: Date = new Date;
    FldUpdatedBy: number = 0;
    FldDesignation: number = 0;
    FldUsername: string = "";
    FldPassword: string = "";
}
```

but when I run the code it is showing blank table.
Now I checked the data in browser console and 'emp' as well as 'emp.FldID' both are displaying correct data. Then why is it not displayed in table?
When I hover over emp in browser source tab, it is showing complete data, but individual emp.FldId in source tab is giving undefined.

Moreover if I give hardcoded data defined in constructor, it is displayed just fine in table.

Comment: Where is part that loading state would be 'false' at your code??? I can't find it. If have not it, please try to add it at constructor... Thank you

Comment: Loading state will be set to false when api data is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are creating the state is not proper

Replace your

`this.state.empList.push(data);`

By

```
this.setState({
   empList: data
})
```

Comment: Please add the fetch function inside the ```componentDidMount()``` function where its recommended to make the API call for the component.
Next add a debugger inside your ```render()``` and check if its getting called after the API responds with some daa

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to fire the API call in the constructor. Please move your API call to the `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('api/Employee/Index')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({loading: false});
        this.setState({empList: data })
      });
  }
```

Also when you have a state as object or Array you should not be mutating it. Because when react does shallow comparison to check whether the state is changed it won't be able to recognize the change because doing `.push()` wont change the reference of the array here .

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount(){
 fetch('api/Employee/Index')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ loading: false,empList:data});
            });
console.log(this.state.empList);
}
```

Comment: `console.log(this.state.empList);` this will not log the data . setting the state and logging it immediately will not work at setState in react is asynchronous .